# Can I find inverse normal in Casio calculator fx- 991ms?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution is given(mean=18 and standard deviation=2.5).
We have to find the value of k for which P(X<k)=0.2578.
It's exhausting to look for the value of z for which the area is 0.2578 from the normal integral table. So how can I find inverse normal in calculator (fx-991ms)?

Comment: It could be that that particular calculator doesn't have that function - at least I don't see it in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

> It's exhausting to look for the value of z for which the area is 0.2578 from the normal integral table

really? it is enough to find the quantile of $1-0.2578=0.7422$ and take the opposit value:

[image]

Result:-0.65

(quicker than pressing a complicated key's combination on a calculator...and works also in a battery low situation)

Comment: I think he's looking for the quantile of $0.2578$, though.

Comment: @Gae.S. : exactly -0.65 as I wrote

Comment: Ah, I see. It did not strike me as obvious that tables for the probit function use only the positive values, but it makes more sense.